# Не пишет в файл

Tags: android, kotlin

Почему-то не пишет в файл.
Импорты:

```
import android.util.Log
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.File
```

Код класса:

```
class SubModel(var name: String, var surname: String, var tel1: String, var tel2: 
String, var email: String) {
fun createSub(sub: SubModel, path: String) {
    val json = JSONObject()

    try {
        json.put("name", sub.name)
        json.put("surname", sub.surname)
        json.put("tel1", sub.tel1)
        json.put("tel2", sub.tel2)
        json.put("email", sub.email)
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
        var file = File(path)
        file.writeText(json.toString(), Charsets.UTF_8)
        Log.d("CREATE", "CREATED")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

}

Использование класса:

```
subModel = SubModel("Anton", "Polyaev", "1111", "2222", "email@gmail.com")
subModel.createSub(subModel, applicationInfo.dataDir + "/data.json")
```

Comment: в чем выражается "не пишет"? ошибки есть? created в лог выводит?

Comment: Да, лог выводит, но по итогу файл пустой

Comment: выглядит так, что с вашим кодом все ок, возможно, вы смотрите файл не по тому пути? `/data/data/<package>/data.json`? попробуйте сохранить в директорию `filesDir` или `cacheDir`.

Answer (score 0):

В Андроид файлы во внутреннем хранилище [принято](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) держать в директориях [`filesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) или [`cacheDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getCacheDir()) вашего приложения:

```kotlin
val file = File(filesDir, "data.json")
file.writeText("content")
```

Возможно, проблема в этом. Либо вы смотрите файл не по тому пути. В остальном, код выглядит рабочим.